# PHP autoloader class to load files from two or three different path

Tags: php, autoloader

I'm learning to use php `autuoloader`...

As much as I understand, we can use `__autoloader` or `spl_autoloader_*` to auto load files.

Assume this is my directories structure :

```
ROOT
  |
  |
  ADMIN
  |  |
  |  |
  |  DIST
  |     |
  |     SOME_FOLDER
  |     SOME_FOLDER
  |  TPL
  |     |
  |     |
  |     SOME_FOLDER1
  |           |
  |           test.php
  |     SOME_FOLDER2
  |           |
  |           example1.php
  |           example2.php
  |           example3.php
  |
  |
  CLASSES
       |
       basics.php
       class1.php
       class2.php
       class3.php
       class4.php
  |
  index.php
```

I made this class for autoload files in `CLASSES` directory :

**basics.php :**

```
class MyAutoLoader
{

    public function __construct()
    {

            spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'load') );

    }




    function load( $file )
    {
        //spl_autoload( 'load1' );

        echo 'Try to call  ' . $file . '.php inside ' . __METHOD__ . '<br>';

        require( $file . '.php' );

    }

}
```

and in `index.php` I will include `basics.php` and every thing is fine for files are stored in `CLASSES` folder...

```
require_once("CLASSES/basics.php");
$loaderObject = new MyAutoLoader();
```

with this code, I can declare `class1` `...` `class3`

Now I want to have an autoloder that could be load files in `SOME_FOLDER2` which in this case are `example1.php` , `example2.php` and `example3.php`

I tried some cases but the files in `SOME_FOLDER2` won't be load using autoloader.

**My attempts :**

I made a function named `load2` in `MyAutoLoader` class that try to include files from `SOME_FOLDER2`

```
function load2( $file )
{
    //spl_autoload_register('load2');

    echo 'Inside LOADER2 ' . __METHOD__ . '<br>';

    require (  'ADMIN/TPL/' . $file . '.php' );

}
```

And I changed `spl_autoload_register` in `MyAutoLoader` constructor :

```
$allMethods = get_class_methods( 'MyAutoLoader' );
$allMethods = array_splice( $allMethods, 1 );

foreach( $allMethods as $method )
{

    spl_autoload_register( array($this, $method) );

}
```

But none of them didn't work for me...

Would you please tell me what's wrong in my code or what is my misunderstanding about auloader?

***`Thanks in Advance`***

Comment: **ATTENTION VISITORS:** please do not use answers below. the entire approach in the question and the answers is horribly wrong. Please follow the duplicate link at the top instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem basically boils down to not checking if the file exists before `require`ing it... that will produce a fatal error if the file doesn't exist in the first folder that you attempt to include from.

I don't know your use case, but here are some suggestions:

Can you just use a single autoloader?

```
function my_autoload($class_name) {
    if (is_file('CLASSES/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once 'CLASSES/' . $class_name . '.php';
    } else if (is_file('ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once 'ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2/' . $class_name . '.php';
    }
}
spl_autoload_register("my_autoload");
```

Or if you need to declare them independently (ie. two or more autoloaders):

```
function classes_autoload($class_name) {
    if (is_file('CLASSES/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once 'CLASSES/' . $class_name . '.php';
    }
}
spl_autoload_register("classes_autoload");

function admin_autoload($class_name) {
    if (is_file('ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once 'ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2/' . $class_name . '.php';
    }
}
spl_autoload_register("admin_autoload");
```

Or make your autoloader class generic:

```
class MyAutoLoader {
    private $path;
    public function __construct($path) {
       $this->path = $path;
       spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'load') );
    }

    function load( $file ) {
        if (is_file($this->path . '/' . $file . '.php')) {
            require_once( $this->path . '/' . $file . '.php' );
        }
    }
}
$autoloader_classes = new MyAutoLoader('CLASSES');
$autoloader_admin = new MyAutoLoader('ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2');
```

If you don't want to manually keep the list of child folders inside `ADMIN/TPL` up to date you could even do something like this to autoload from any of them (this obviously assumes that all subfolders of `ADMIN/TPL` contains classes):

```
function my_autoload($class_name) {
    if (is_file('CLASSES/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once 'CLASSES/' . $class_name . '.php';
    } else {
        $matching_files = glob('ADMIN/TPL/*/' . $class_name . '.php');
        if (count($matching_files) === 1) {
            require_once $matching_files[0];
        } else if (count($matching_files) === 0) {
            trigger_error('Could not find class ' . $class_name . '!', E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            trigger_error('More than one possible match found for class ' . $class_name . '!', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register("my_autoload");
```

Comment: Thanks you for showing us different different ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may actually be as simple as this:

Your `basics.php` is inside the folder `CLASSES`, so when you `include` or `require` files from within `basics.php` it starts in that folder.

So if you want to include files from `ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2` you actually need to "jump" up one level first, ie `require '../ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2/' . $file . '.php';`

To avoid this kind of confusion I would recommend adding a constant to the beginning of `index.php` like this:

```
define('BASEPATH', __DIR__);
```

...and then prepending that to all `require` and `include` statements - ie:

```
class MyAutoLoader {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'load') );
        spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'load2') );
    }
    function load( $file ) {
        echo 'Try to call  ' . $file . '.php inside ' . __METHOD__ . '<br>';
        $classfile = BASEPATH . '/CLASSES/' . $file . '.php';
        if ( is_file( $classfile ) ) {
            require( $classfile );
        }
    }
    function load2( $file ) {
        echo 'Try to call  ' . $file . '.php inside ' . __METHOD__ . '<br>';
        $classfile = BASEPATH . '/ADMIN/TPL/SOME_FOLDER2/' . $file . '.php';
        if ( is_file( $classfile ) ) {
            require( $classfile );
        }
    }
}
```